# Django registration - redirect from login/register after successful login

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm using `django-registration` and I need to prevent access to login, register etc when the user is logged in. Now, when the user is logged in I can access `/accounts/register/``. How to prevent this?

I think to overwrite this view but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I've only used the built-in Django auth, but could you redirect the user in your 'register' view based on whether or not they're logged in?

```
def register(request):
    user = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'already_logged_in.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html')
```